# Map items to html file with Google Apps Script file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script WebApp that automates emails for particular events with webhooks.

I have an array of objects which i need to map to the html template file in the same directory.

For example, my Code.gs file looks like this:

```
function doThing() {
  if ('Some condtition' === true) {
    let template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('my-template')

    let items = [
      { name: 'John Smith', age: 20, address: '123 fakestreet' },
      { name: 'Sam Smith', age: 27, address: '123 fakestreet' },
      { name: 'Phil Smith', age: 10, address: '123 fakestreet' }
    ]

    template.items = items

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: 'John@gmail.com',
      subject: 'This is an automated email',
      htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()
    })
  }
}
```

And the my-template.html file looks like this:

```
<body>
<!-- This is how to call the passed variable -->
    <?= items ?> 

    <!-- I want to map my items like this -->
    <div>
        <div>John Smith</div>
        <div>20</div>
        <div>123 fakestreet</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Sam Smith</div>
        <div>27</div>
        <div>123 fakestreet</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Phil Smith</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>123 fakestreet</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried using script tags in the html file but they don't seem to be being executed, probably because its emailed.

I have also tried to map each item to a string and pass the string to the html like this:

```
let items = '<div>
        <div>John Smith</div>
        <div>20</div>
        <div>123 fakestreet</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Sam Smith</div>
        <div>27</div>
        <div>123 fakestreet</div>
    </div>...'
```

But that just writes the string with the tags.

Comment: Read examples in the documentation, specifically standard scriplets. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: In your situation, is it required to use the HTML template? For example, how about directly using the HTML body like `htmlBody: "<body>" + items.reduce((s, e) => (s += "<div>" + Object.entries(e).map(([,f]) => "<div>" + f + "</div>").join("") + "</div>"), "") + "</body>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over `items` using [standard scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates):

```html
<? for(const item of items){?>
   <div>
        <div><?= item.name ?></div>
        <div><?= item.age ?></div>
        <div><?= item.address ?></div>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scriplets**

As per docs, there are exactly three types of scriplets:

1. **Standard** - enclosed code is executed with *no output*
2. **Printing** - *return* value is *escaped* and *outputted*
3. **Force-printing** - same as printing, but value is *not escaped*

The difference between printing and force-printing might be easier to grasp visually:

```js
document.querySelector('#escaped').textContent += '<a href="#">this is a link</a>';
```

```html
<p id="escaped">
  Here lies an escaped output: 
</p>

<p>
  Here lives an unescaped output: 
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611359/map-items-to-html-file-with-google-scripts-file">this is a link</a>
<p>
```

**What else to try**

Since you probalby use V8 and are likely not dealing with untrusted input (in `items`) `Array`, you can take advantage of the newest features (+ I agree that evaluating a template for a simple markup is overkill):

*No template*

```
const divify = (text) => `<div>${text}</div>`;

const itemsMarkup = items
  .map(item => {
    const { address, age, name } = item;
    return divify(divify(name) + divify(age) + divify(address));
  })
  .join("");
```

**Notes**

1. `=== true` in conditionals is usually excessive, they will execute the block associated with truthy / falsy result of evaluating the expression (note that strings are also truthy): `if('Some condtition')`.
2. *because its emailed* - no, evaluation is performed before `sendEmail()`, key `htmlBody` receives an html string resulting from template evaluation and subsequent content extraction.
3. *mid-edit-note*: since TheMaster's answer and Tanaike's comment deal with the problem, so I modified the answer to be a supplement explanation.
4. Do you really need the `<body>` tag, divs will be rendered just fine (if you are feeling pedantic - wrap them into a `<div>`)?

**Reference**

1. [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values in JS
2. Object initializer [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
3. Templated HTML [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: [hm, I could swear there was a comment before] Thanks, @TheMaster. Re: conditionals - I may have misused the term - I find implicit marginally faster in most cases + less cluttery, but I tend to use `if(arr.length)` if comparing against consistent arrays as output. Do you think of a particular method? 

I misspelled the term anyway, so might as well correct it :)

Comment: I saw you have referenced Truthy. So I deleted my comment. In case of `arr.length`, it's certain that it'll always be a number and it'll be 0, when length is 0. However, if `'Some condtition'` is say, a complex function returning `true` or a empty array `[]`(for `false`). Though it's a badly written function, `===` will save you. Especially beginners should write everything explicitly. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Ah, I see - thank you for elaborating (and indeed, it makes sense if the function is inconsistent - I don't see the reason behind using it as a test in the first place, though). Anyway, I do agree with the principle - just think that if you know what you are doing, you can surely "cut corners" (unless damaging maintainability, ofc)